# SharePoint online: Show image instead of text description on hyperlink hover

Tags: sharepoint-online, hyperlink, image

Is it possible to force SharePoint to show an image instead of text description while mouseover a hyperlink on my SharePoint-wiki based website?

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge,the default feature of OOTB does not support this requirement, it requires redevelopment of the code.

You can also go to [SharePoint UserVoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/) to make your suggestions.

Comment: ...which means that in my case it's not worth further investigation. Thanks, for help.